# Set absolute positioned child to 100% width of parent including border

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.parent , .child{
    border: 10px solid black;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 background:green;
}
.child{
 background:blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
Parent Element
<div class="child">
Child Element
</div>
</div>
```

While this can achieved with changing the width to `calc(100% + 20px);` is there a more dynamic way of making sure the bottom div is aligned with the top (without using flex boxes)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `left: -10px`, why not simply use `right: -10px` instead of setting the width.

```css
.parent , .child{
    border: 10px solid black;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 background:green;
}
.child{
 background:blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    top: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
Parent Element
<div class="child">
Child Element
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this would achieve the result, it still has the problem of not being flexible enough. It still requires a concrete value for the left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: Don't make it a child, and omit the top border.

```css
.parent , .child{
    border: 10px solid black;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 background:green;
}
.child{
 background:blue;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
Parent Element
</div>
<div class="child">
Child Element
</div>
```

Comment: While this would also work, it unfortunately would not work for how I have to have the data structured.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the border with box-shadow on the parent element

```css
.parent,
.child {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px inset black;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: green;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Parent Element
  <div class="child">
    Child Element
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea with background:

```css
.parent,
.child {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(green,green) content-box,
   #000;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  border:10px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Parent Element
  <div class="child">
    Child Element
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This could possibly work, unfortunately though I am already using the box shadow in the real world example. It seems like this is not something that can be done.

Comment: @Robbie you can have multiple box-shadow, I can also add gradient, etc